# Sequence of PHP Scripts in Bash script executed by Cron not running

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have four PHP scripts that perform various tasks that need to be executed sequentially.

Instead of creating a cron entry for each PHP script, I thought I would be clever and wrap it up as a Bash script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set notification email.
NOTIFYEMAIL="webmaster@example.com"

# set PHP path.
PHP="$(which php)"

# set folder path.
FOLDER="/var/www/example.com/processors/"

# list of scripts.
SCRIPTS=("script_1" "script_2" "script_3" "script_4")

# execute each script.
for i in "${SCRIPTS[@]}"
do
    SCRIPT="$FOLDER/$i.php"
    printf "Processing: %s\n" $i
    chmod +x $SCRIPT
    $PHP $SCRIPT
done

echo "Scripts have been processed." | mail -s "Scripts Processed" $NOTIFYEMAIL
```

I've tested all the scripts individually, and they work without error, outputting processing information to the terminal.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/processors/script_1.php
```

I've even tested the bash script which calls the four PHP scripts in sequence, manually via the terminal and that also works without error.

```
/bin/bash /var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh
```

But for some reason, the PHP scripts don't execute when I leave cron to run them using the following on the **root** users crontab.

```
# process daily.
0 1 * * * /bin/bash /var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh > /dev/null
```

I know that the crontab has been processed and the Bash script has run because I always receive the notification e-mail at the end of the script, each and every time.

Permissions are as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     510 Mar 11 09:21 run.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 git git      2.8K Mar  8 10:17 script_1.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 git git      2.6K Mar  1 18:07 script_2.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 git git       717 Mar  1 18:07 script_3.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 git git      6.8K Mar  4 16:30 script_4.php
```

There are no cron-specific log files such as `/var/log/cron.log` but when I run `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and it returns the following generic output:

```
Mar 11 06:39:01 s00000000 CRON[11651]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Mar 11 07:09:01 s00000000 CRON[12771]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Mar 11 07:17:01 s00000000 CRON[13074]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Any suggestions for things for me to try would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the chown/chmod rights of run.sh look like? PS: Might be a question for http://serverfault.com/

Is `root` able/allowed to execute the `run.sh` / `script_1.php`?

Comment: ... and the `php` scripts itself? do you have root access to test-run `/bin/bash /var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh` by console?

Comment: surely root should have access to run everything?

Comment: @simplyray I've updated with permissions on those files. I deploy the site with Git and `chmod +x` on the files within the Bash script.

Comment: @paperclip: hmm okay ... any error log entries for the crontab under `/var/log`?

Comment: You said you tested the scripts. Were you testing from the PHP directory or some other directory?

Comment: @Danack I've run it from the home directory and from the same directory of the PHP scripts. But each time I've used the full paths to the scripts.

Comment: @simplyray I've checked `/var/log` and there are no cron-specific log files such as `/var/log/cron.log` but I did run `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and it returns the following: http://pastie.org/pastes/6449288/text?key=dtyzcblc3wxnpglx7b7fma

Comment: @paperclip: try `grep -i cron /var/log/*`. If the cron really executes there should be entries like: `CRON[<PID>]: (root) CMD (/var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh) *`

Comment: @simplyray Found this entry: `Mar 11 01:00:01 s00000000 CRON[591]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh > /dev/null)`

Comment: @paperclip: ok that`s good. Command seems to be executed. Try debugging the cron by outputting it to a seperate logfile, e.g.:

`bin/bash /var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh > /my/custom/path/logs/cron.log 2>&1`

By using `2>&1` you make sure to log standard output *and* errors to your custom logfile

Comment: i would sugest running the PHP files in the cron job with specific php path, when manually testing them as a root/other user PHP command might be recognized, for cron job specify the php path and then run the comand, for example /var/php/php  /usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/processors/script_1.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preliminary

- Check that in the crontab the values of `SHELL` and `PATH` are set up correctly, e.g.:

  ```
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
  ```

  - Ensure that the intended shell (e.g. bash) is really used.
  - Ensure that all needed binaries are accessible via the denoted `PATH`.
- Check that you don't have an unescaped `%` in the crontab. See `man 5 crontab` for details.
- Maybe you set also the environment variable `MAILTO` to an approbate value, e.g.:

  ```
  MAILTO="webmaster@example.com"
  ```

#### Ensure your crontab is working

Another little trick to ensure that your *crontab* is parsed correct, is to add a *marker* entry at the **end**.

I'm using myself this marker entry

> @daily logger -p local0.notice -t CRON '$Id: demo 7029 2012-11-27 09:27:39Z dirk $'

If the marker entry is missing in the syslog, you know that the *crontab* has become corrupted. This may be triggered by some weird syntax error you haven't seen.

#### How to debug a cron job

If a cron job it not working please investigate first the job output.

Change your crontab to:

```
0 1 * * * /bin/bash -x /var/www/example.com/processors/run.sh >>/tmp/cronTrace 2>&1
```

Please investigate the generated script output together with the trace output (`bash -x`).

#### Additional  note

<strike>`chmod +x $SCRIPT`</strike>
`$PHP $SCRIPT`

The `chmod` step is not necessary and should be avoided.
In the next line you invoke the script by explicitly use the interpreter command.

Comment: Can you elaborate on adding a marker to the crontab and how to check whether the values for `SHELL` and `PATH` are setup correctly in the crontab.

Comment: After letting it run with logging to a file as suggested it created an empty log file. No output at all.

Comment: @paperclip This is only be possible, if the script file is empty. If the script file has at least one (none-comment) line, it is traced with the `-x` option.